# Frame-by-frame animation in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations

I'm interested in producing high-quality mathematical animations for educational purposes, in a similar style to [1ucasvb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:LucasVB/Gallery). At first I tried experimenting with Adobe Animate (formerly known as Adobe Flash), however I wasn't satisfied with the lack of access to mathematical tools (the basic drawing tools only get you polygons and ellipses). I was after an environment which will allow me to precisely draw mathematical shapes such as the graph of the sine function, or the zero-set of some polynomials. Another issue is that I'm not very skillful in drawing by hand (or by mouse/stylus).

Now, I've been using LaTeX for some time, and I like the control it gives you by coding the document. I'm considering using LaTeX and in particular PGF/TikZ for my animations. Some of my questions/comments are:

- Is using LaTeX/PGF/TikZ a reasonable choice? I imagine it will take a lot of work to produce the frames individually, but is it feasible?
- If using LaTeX/PGF/TikZ is a bad choice, I'd appreciate information on any other way of producing such mathematical animations, with about the same level of precision.
- If using LaTeX/PGF/TikZ is a reasonable choice, what would the work template look like? Should I use beamer, for instance?

Thank you!

Comment: It is very convenient to use Ti*k*Z for animations and this site is full of examples. Just look for "tikz" and "animate", for instance.

Comment: “Is X a good choice?”, “Suggest a good package for X to me.” and “Should I use X?” are opinion-based questions.  Voting to close.  Also, please never ask more than questions at the same time.

Comment: @HenriMenke My apologies if my questions are opinion based. In any case, marmot's comment has put me on the right track. I think you dropped the upper bound on the limit on the number of my questions in the final part of your comment. Could you please tell me what it is? Thanks.